# C segmentation fault when I try to open file

Tags: c, file-io, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to input data from a file into a struct but whenever i try to input the path in the "filename" variable it gives me a segmentation fault in terminal:

```
Goods Re-Order File program
Enter database file
/stock.txt
Segmentation fault
```

This is my code. Also I'm currently running osx 10.5.8 if that is relevant.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

struct goods
{
    char name[20];
    float price;
    int quantity;
    int reorder;
};
FILE *input_file;
void processfile(void);
void getrecord(struct goods *recptr);
void printrecord(struct goods record);
int main(void)
{
    char filename[40];
    printf("Goods Re-Order File program\n");
    printf("Enter database file\n");
    scanf("%s",filename);
    //strcpy(filename,"/stock.txt");
   //gets(filename);

    input_file=fopen(filename,"r");
    if(!input_file)
    {
        printf("Could not open file!\n");
    }
    processfile();
    fclose(input_file);
    return 0;
}
void processfile(void)
{
    struct goods record;
    while(!feof(input_file))
    {
        getrecord(&record);
        if(record.quantity<=record.reorder)
        {
            printrecord(record);
        }
    }
}

void getrecord(struct goods *recptr)
{
    int loop=0,number,toolow;
    char buffer[40],ch;
    float cost;
    ch=fgetc(input_file);
    while (ch!='\n')
    {
        buffer[loop++]=ch;
        ch=fgetc(input_file);
    }
    buffer[loop]=0;
    strcpy(recptr->name,buffer);
    fscanf(input_file,"%f",&cost);
    recptr->price=cost;
    fscanf(input_file,"%d",&number);
    recptr->quantity=number;
    fscanf(input_file,"%d",&toolow);
    recptr->reorder=toolow;
}
void printrecord(struct goods record)
{
    printf("\nProduct name\t%s\n",record.name);
    printf("Product price \t%f\n",record.price);
    printf("Product quantity \t%d\n",record.quantity);
    printf("Product reorder level \t%d\n",record.reorder);
}
```

Comment: Are you typing more than 39 characters in?   Also, you don't actually exit the program if the `if (!input_file)` test fails, you go on to call `processfile()` anyway, which may segfault if `input_file` is NULL.

Comment: In goods, name is 20 chars and getrecord reserves 40 chars but your loop never checks these bounds.

Comment: `while(!feof(input_file))` what do you imagine happens if you read the last element of the file inside the while loop? You won't have read the end of the file yet, and then you'll try to read another one when one doesn't exist `if(record.quantity<=record.reorder)`

Comment: Just run it in debugger and see where exactly it fails.

Comment: By the way, `while (!feof(input_file))` isn't the right way to read records out of a file. `feof` is not a check to see whether you are at the end of the file or not, despite its name. Instead, have your `getrecord` function return success or failure, and exit your loop when `getrecord` fails.  You will have to modify `getrecord` to be able to detect input failure;  change `char ch;` to `int ch;`, and after you call `fgetc`, check if `ch == EOF`, and if so, return the failure code. As things stand, `getrecord` will go into an infinite loop if it hits EOF before `\n`, which would segfault.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is here:

```
while(!feof(input_file))
```

you should read only at the end of the while loop. Try this:

```
struct goods record;
getrecord(&record);
while(!feof(input_file))
{

    if(record.quantity<=record.reorder)
    {
        printrecord(record);
    }
    getrecord(&record);
}
```

You will also need to modify `getrecord` to exit if `EOF` is found.

Something like this (untested):

```
void getrecord(struct goods *recptr)
{
    int loop=0,number,toolow;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int ch;
    float cost;
    ch=fgetc(input_file);
    if (ch == EOF) //if last element already read, will be EOF
       return; 
    while (ch!='\n' && ch != EOF && loop < BUFFER_SIZE) //BUFFER_SIZE
    {
        buffer[loop++]=(char)ch;
        ch=fgetc(input_file);
    }
    if (ch == EOF) //check for unexpected EOF
       return;
    //...
```

You could also change `getrecord` to return `true` or `false` based on whether `EOF` was read.

Comment: You should also check for buffer overflow in the loop.

Comment: Did that by making the name variable of the structure to be size 40.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp: Added the check. The function will exit if the buffer is filled, but there is no guarantee that a newline is the last character read, so OP may or may not want to account for that.

Answer (score 2):

After you are unable to open the file you do the check but need a return

i.e.

```
if(!input_file)
{
    printf("Could not open file!\n");
    return -1;
}
```

**EDIT**

The loop in `getrecord` should be

```
while (ch!='\n' && ch != EOF && loop < 39)
{
    buffer[loop++]=ch;
    ch=fgetc(input_file);
}
```

So you do not overrun the buffer.

Also the structure should be (as buffer could be 40 characters)

```
struct goods
{
   char name[40];
```

BTW - Not a good idea to store money as floats

Comment: Did that at first, for some reason gave me a compile error, now it doesn't. Guess I didn't pay attention :) Thanks. Still gives me a segmentation fault though.

Comment: At first I compiled the code [without making name[40]] and it actually spat out something THEN it gave me a segmentation fault:
Enter database file
/stock.txt

3roduct name Greaters ice-cream
Product price  2.562500
Product quantity  -1609231168
Product reorder level  -1609229604
Segmentation fault

now i made the name array to be size 40 and when i try to open "/stock.txt" it does nothing.

Comment: @The_0bserver - best bet is to use the debugger

Comment: Trying to do that but everything is greyed out in the debugger filemenu in code::blocks...Perhaps I need a different IDE..